# Upload file using "hidden" iframe doesn't work in explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have this form html:

```
<form id="testForm" method="post" action="upload.php" target="upload_target" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <textarea name="infoText"></textarea>
    <input id="file-input" name="bid-file" type="file" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtnFile" style="visibility:hidden;">
</form>
<button id="#submitBtn">Submit</button>

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

My js is:

```
$('#submitBid').click( function(){
    $('#objectCommentsSubmit').trigger('click');
    $('#submitBtnFile').trigger('click');
    $('.loading-bid').show();
});
```

This works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome but not in IE!

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong for IE?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `objectCommentsSubmit`? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Oh..why did that get there?! Nope, no console errors.

Comment: Wait, seems I got an error in the console after all:
"script5: access is denied"
"jqeuru-1.7.1.min.js, line 3 character 3385"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('#submitBtnFile').trigger('click');
```

to

```
$("#testForm").submit();
```

Comment: get this error in the console: 
"script5: access is denied" 
"jqeury-1.7.1.min.js, line 3 character 3385"

Comment: I had to remove both trigger()'s for it to work. IE doesn't play nice when you use trigger() inside of forms.